# Insert Formula in Offset column

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple sheets in a workbook and am looking to write a formula for all the worksheets using a single code. So in column Q i need to search for a string called Balance and in the adjacent column write a simple sum formula. But my code seems to be failing at a particular point where the formula is placed. If someone can point me whats my mistake. Thanks in advance

```
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Dim c1 as Range
    Dim searchValue As String
    searchValue = "BALANCE"
    For Each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Control" And ws.Name <> "Combined" Then
    With ws
    Nextrow = .Range("Q" &.Rows.Count.End(xlUp).Row+1
    ws.Range("Q" & Nextrow) = "BALANCE"
    Set c1 = .Range("q4:q" & .cells(.Rows.count,"q").End(xlUp).Row).Find(searchValue)
    End With
    If Not C1 is Nothing then C1.Offset(0,1).Formula2Local = "=SUM(R4:R")"
    Else
    End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to locate `BALANCE` in Col Q because it is updated by VBA code.

- `c1` is the last cell in Col Q
- Write `BALANCE` on `c1` and apply formula to the next right cell

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim c1 As Range
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Control" And ws.Name <> "Combined" Then
            With ws
                Set c1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp)
            End With
            c1.Value = "BALANCE"
            c1.Offset(0, 1).Formula2Local = "=SUM(R4:R" & c1.Row & ")"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Add Totals Below Column Data

[image]

**A Quick Fix**

```
Sub AddBalanceTotalQF()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim nextRow As Long
    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Control" And ws.Name <> "Combined" Then
            With ws
                nextRow = .Range("Q" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Range("Q" & nextRow) = "BALANCE"
                .Range("R" & nextRow).Formula = "=SUM(R4:R" & nextRow - 1 & ")"
            End With
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

**Some Ideas**

```vb
Sub AddBalanceTotal()

    Const FIRST_CELL As String = "Q4"
    Const BALANCE_COLUMN As String = "R"

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rCount As Long, IsFound As Boolean
    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case LCase(ws.Name)
            Case "control", "combined"
            Case Else
                IsFound = True
        End Select
        If IsFound Then
            IsFound = False
            With ws.Range(FIRST_CELL)
                rCount _
                    = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
                If rCount < 1 Then
                    MsgBox "No data found.", vbExclamation
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                .Offset(rCount).Value = "BALANCE"
                With .EntireRow.Columns(BALANCE_COLUMN)
                    .Offset(rCount).Formula _
                        = "=SUM(" & .Resize(rCount).Address(0, 0) & ")"
                End With
            End With
        End If
    Next ws
            
End Sub
```